# Perl Template Toolkit - how to join / concat multiple variables (into one)

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

Perl Template Toolkit - how to join / concat multiple variables (into one)
for example wanting it when selecting the chosen element in a html select field/combo.

I found the question here https://www.perlmonks.org/?displaytype=print;replies=1;node_id=880584 , but it did not seem to be properly replied.

Dots, spaces or plus signs didn't help to join variables.

Edit:
previously I managed to work it around just by using interpolation inside a string

```
[% var = "$var1-$var2-$var3" %]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

String concatenation is done with the underscore `_`. See [the manual here](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html#section_SET). It's a bit hidden.

```
[%
   SET $foo = $bar _ $asdf _ " " _ $xyz
%]
```

For your example, that would be done like this, but interpolation works just as well.

```
[% var = $var1 _ "-" _ $var2 _ "-" _ $var3 %]
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, however this does not seem to work inside this special case an array definition in template toolkit like this ` [% form = [ [ 'Date:' , todayDate _ macroSelectBox(data)  ] %]  ` . Any clues with this?

Comment: I worked this around ` [% form = [ [ 'Date:' , todayDate _ macroSelectBox(data) ] %] ` by using another inner nested array and joining it later like this, but its a bit crude , ` [% form = [ [ 'Date:' , [ todayDate ,  macroSelectBox(data) ]  ] %] `

Comment: @FantomX1 that is odd. You could make the second element in its own var first and put it in the array later?

Comment: @simbaque thanks, thats also an option I was considering, but its not very transparent for example my array is 10 rows long, doing it like this its going to make it about twice that size = 20 additional rows for setting variables, just because of this

Comment: @FantomX1 can you not do that in the backend rather than in the template? Or create anotehr `macroSelectBoxDate(data, todayDate)`?

Comment: @simbaque yeah good thoughts, I could make it in the backend, but I feel like that approach is not very practical , effective and good practice. Another macro could work, but its still much more hassle I guess, than just joining them. The conclusion its syntax of template toolkit joining can't be said that works in any context of the template toolkit usages, since I did not exit template toolkit domain language ,  I presume, when I used it inside an array definition, I did not applied the perl tag, moreover, if it was raw perl, at least other options would work